# Re-Training CNN with new Data

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I built a CNN to classify 10 different classes. It performs well on most of the classes, giving approx. 80-85% accu. per class. Current each class has 10000+ images

But in the future, there is a possibility that I might get more data for each class.

For instance, I get more data for some class, how should I re-train the model?

1. Should I retrain the entire thing i.e with old and new data?
2. Should I retrain the model with only new data? Here, I fear that as the model will get new data for a single class, the model can possibly forget what it has already learned or might affect the accuracies of other classes.

If anyone has worked on this problem before, please help......

Comment: You should retrain from scratch on the updated dataset